# AngularJS page is not loading to newbie

Tags: angularjs

My task is to show `Hello, Angular!` in the browser, using AngularJS.

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Introduction to AngularJS Application</title>
        <script src="Scripts/MyScripts/Example01Scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```js
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />
var MainController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!";
};
```

And here's what I'm getting:

[image: <h1>{{message}}</h1>]

This is my expected result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Introduction to AngularJS Application</title>
        <script src="Scripts/MyScripts/Example01Scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <h1>Hello, Angular!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The interpolation isn't functioning correctly. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: where you declared module ? what is module name ?

Comment: You don't seem to be including the angularjs library itself.

Comment: @Sergiu: I have added angular.js as a reference inside my JavaScript file

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi: Do I need to declare module? Is it mandatory? As I am newbie, I have never heard about it that it is must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your code and updated it. You were missing the app name in `ng-app`. Click `Run code snippet` to see it working.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!";
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Introduction to AngularJS Application</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the HTML you're missing the Angular source code and your app name on ng-app directive.

On the JS you're missing the module declaration.

HTML should be something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>Introduction to AngularJS Application</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/MyScripts/Example01Scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and your Example01Scripts.js should be something like:

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!";
});
```

Comment: though I'd prefer splitting the JS into myApp.js for the module declaration and a myApp.ctrl.js for the Controller declaration

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the module was missing. Have created a wee test script that will do what you wanted.

[Code example here](http://jsbin.com/sufagejewu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Please post your code into the answer, so that if the link breaks, it's not useless.